# How to install mk-livestatus on nagios?

Tags: nagios

I am using `Check_MK` with `Nagios`. I found somewhere that nagios comes with mk-livestatus but I found on my server but I couldn't found it.

Can we add this(mk-livestatus) feature explicitely? If Yes, How could I install it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OMD` automatically configures this option correctly in `etc/mk-livestatus/nagios.cfg`.

If your nagios is not configured with OMD you can use following steps to install mk-livestatus:

**- Installing mk livestatus:**

1.- Install dependencies:

```
# yum install make gcc-c++ wget
```

2.- Download mk livestatus:

```
# cd /tmp && wget http://mathias-kettner.de/download/mk-livestatus-1.1.12p7.tar.gz
```

3.- Extract package:

```
# tar -xzvf mk-livestatus-1.1.12p7.tar.gz
```

4.- Install:

```
# cd mk-livestatus-1.1.12p7/ && ./configure
# make && make install
```

5.- Create new directory with correct permissions:

```
# mkdir /usr/lib/nagios/mk-livestatus && chown nagios:apache /usr/lib/nagios/mk-livestatus
```

6.- Edit /etc/nagios/nagios.cfg :

```
broker_module=/usr/local/lib/mk-livestatus/livestatus.o /usr/lib/nagios/mk-livestatus/live
```

7.- Restart Nagios:

```
# service nagios restart
```

8.- Try command line:

```
# echo 'GET hosts' | unixcat /usr/lib/nagios/mk-livestatus/live
```

For more information of query syntax:

http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, the last example `'GET hosts'` is very restrictive because if you want to do *anything* else, you need a newline, and you can't do that with this syntax. In that case, you need to do something like this: `echo -e "GET services\nColumns: host_name description state" (...)`

Answer (score -1):

There is a website specially for mk_livestatus made by mathias kettner who's the creator of mk_livestatus

here the installation documentation for the agent on linux ( dpkg or rpm )

http://mathias-kettner.com/checkmk_linuxagent.html

Comment: The URL mentioned by you is about installing the `check_mk_agent` not `mk-livestatus`